# SQL: Where clause at 2 places in sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a unique requirement where I have to fetch data from more than one table and  I do not afford to hit more than 1 SQL query.

There are 2 tables, `Table1` and `Table2`.

Columns in `Table 1` are:

```
C1    C2    C3
----------------
1     1     10
2     3     20
3     5     30
4     8     40
```

Columns in `Table 2` are:

```
C1    C2    C3
---------------
1     1     10
2     3     20
3     5     30
4     8     40
```

The query logically goes like this: (This is syntactically not running)

```
select
    (t1.c1) as alias1,
    (sum(t1.c2) **where t1.c3>20**) as alias2,
    (t1.c2) as alias3,
    (t2.c2) as alias4
from 
    Table1 t1
left join 
    Table2 t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c2
**where t1.c1** in ('1','2','3')
group by ....
```

Please ignore the syntax of the query.

My question is there are 2 places where I have applied **where clause** and that is what I have to do as I cannot pull the inner where out as that would eventually hamper my result set and alias3 wold be incorrect in that case.

Do I have any other option than breaking the query into 2 queries?

I am getting

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"

in my playpen and I will not be able to share the real query. But the gist is same.

Comment: `sum(case when t1.c3>20 then t1.c2 else 0 end) as alias2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `filter()` clause for aggregates:

```
select t1.c1 as alias1,
       sum(t1.c2) filter (where t1.c3>20) as alias2,
       t1.c2 as alias3,
       t2.c2 as alias4
from Table1 t1
  left join Table2 t2 on t1.c1=t2.c2
where t1.c1 in (1,2,3)
group by ....
```

---

Putting individual (single) columns between parentheses is completely useless.